# Python FTP return corrupted name of file: じし->し ゙し (how can i properly decode/encode a string)

Tags: python, string, character-encoding, cjk, ftplib

In my open source application, I use rented hosting with FTP. My application needs to read a list of files from a directory and parse it. However, some of the files have erroneous names. How can I recover the names or ask FTP to give them out correctly.

```
import ftplib

ftp_domain = "japcards.ru"
ftp_login = "u1670424_jap_db"
ftp_pass = "Jap2DbPass"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftp_domain)
    ftp.encoding = 'utf-8'
    ftp.login(ftp_login, ftp_pass)
    ftp.cwd("audio/jp")
    ftpList = ftp.nlst()
    ftpList.sort()
    for i in ftpList:
        print(i)
        print(i.encode('utf-8'))
```

From the output of the example:

```
し ゙しょけい.wav
b'\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x82\x99\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x82\x87\xe3\x81\x91\xe3\x81\x84.wav'
```

Comment: when you say erroneous, what exactly are you referring to? 
it may be worth showing what your desired output would be in the question.

Comment: I want to get "じしょけい.wav" but I get "し ゙しょけい.wav" instead.

Comment: In other words, 1 character turns into 2 separate ones.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to just be an issue with how your OS / STDOUT is handling the characters.

As you have shown with the encoded output, the character `じ` is represented by `\xE3\x81\x97\xE3\x82\x99` and when you inspect the variable in memory, those bytes are treated as a single UTF-8 character.

If you paste the "desired" text into your IDE, PyCharm Windows in my case, the `\xE3\x81\x97\xE3\x82\x99` is replaced with `\xE3\x81\x97\x20\xE3\x82\x99`

Outside of printing on the screen, this issue shouldn't affect the rest of your code. As in memory the file names are preserved fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, he turned out to be wrong.

Comment: I did some research and found out that this is a library bug in my version of FTP (Python 3.8). If you install Python 3.10.4, this problem disappears.

Comment: `Outside of printing on the screen, this issue shouldn't affect the rest of your code. As in memory the file names are preserved fine.`
There is a difference when comparing ("==") two strings. If you read the filename of a file from the file system, the name is correct. And when compared, this name does not match the string from FTP.

Comment: yea i would suspect that your OS was returning the file name with the extra character. Thats just interop stuff that we dont have much control ever, thankfully the Python devs addressed that. @ВадимДерябкин

Comment: In the terminal I see the same thing. But I can't compare strings. Do you know how can I compare these two strings correctly? (I want to get True) `じしょけい \xe3\x81\x98\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x82\x87\xe3\x81\x91\xe3\x81\x84` and `じしょけい \xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x82\x99\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x82\x87\xe3\x81\x91\xe3\x81\x84'`

Comment: Okey. I find answer: https://igreks.jp/dev/%E6%BF%81%E7%82%B9%EF%BC%88%E3%82%9B%EF%BC%89%E3%81%A8%E5%8D%8A%E6%BF%81%E7%82%B9%EF%BC%88%E3%82%9C%EF%BC%89%E3%82%92%E5%90%AB%E3%82%80%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB/

Comment: @ВадимДерябкин can you provide a link to the library bug?

Comment: I suppose it was [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83561).

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer: you need to run the script with a version of at least Python 3.10.4.
For compare strings (duplicate from website):

```
$str = "がぎぐげござじずぜぞだぢづでど・・・";
 
# Hiragana
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\x8B\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\x8C/g;  # か+○゛=> が
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\x8D\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\x8E/g;  # き+○゛=> ぎ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\x8F\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\x90/g;  # く+○゛=> ぐ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\x91\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\x92/g;  # け+○゛=> げ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\x93\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\x94/g;  # こ+○゛=> ご
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\x95\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\x96/g;  # さ+○゛=> ざ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\x97\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\x98/g;  # し+○゛=> じ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\x99\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\x9A/g;  # す+○゛=> ず
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\x9B\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\x9C/g;  # せ+○゛=> ぜ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\x9D\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\x9E/g;  # そ+○゛=> ぞ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\x9F\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\xA0/g;  # た+○゛=> だ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xA1\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\xA2/g;  # ち+○゛=> ぢ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xA4\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\xA5/g;  # つ+○゛=> づ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xA6\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\xA7/g;  # て+○゛=> で
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xA8\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\xA9/g;  # と+○゛=> ど
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xAF\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\xB0/g;  # は+○゛=> ば
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xAF\xE3\x82\x9A/\xE3\x81\xB1/g;  # は+○゜=> ぱ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xB2\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\xB3/g;  # ひ+○゛=> び
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xB2\xE3\x82\x9A/\xE3\x81\xB4/g;  # ひ+○゜=> ぴ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xB5\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\xB6/g;  # ふ+○゛=> ぶ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xB5\xE3\x82\x9A/\xE3\x81\xB7/g;  # ふ+○゜=> ぷ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xB8\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\xB9/g;  # へ+○゛=> べ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xB8\xE3\x82\x9A/\xE3\x81\xBA/g;  # へ+○゜=> ぺ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xBB\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x81\xBC/g;  # ほ+○゛=> ぼ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x81\xBB\xE3\x82\x9A/\xE3\x81\xBD/g;  # ほ+○゜=> ぽ
 
# Katakana
$str =~ s/\xE3\x82\xAB\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x82\xAC/g;  # カ+○゛=> ガ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x82\xAD\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x82\xAE/g;  # キ+○゛=> ギ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x82\xAF\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x82\xB0/g;  # ク+○゛=> グ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x82\xB1\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x82\xB2/g;  # ケ+○゛=> ゲ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x82\xB3\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x82\xB4/g;  # コ+○゛=> ゴ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x82\xB5\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x82\xB6/g;  # サ+○゛=> ザ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x82\xB7\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x82\xB8/g;  # シ+○゛=> ジ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x82\xB9\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x82\xBA/g;  # ス+○゛=> ズ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x82\xBB\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x82\xBC/g;  # セ+○゛=> ゼ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x82\xBD\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x82\xBE/g;  # ソ+○゛=> ゾ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x82\xBF\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x83\x80/g;  # タ+○゛=> ダ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x81\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x83\x82/g;  # チ+○゛=> ヂ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x84\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x83\x85/g;  # ツ+○゛=> ヅ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x86\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x83\x87/g;  # テ+○゛=> デ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x88\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x83\x89/g;  # ト+○゛=> ド
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x8F\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x83\x90/g;  # ハ+○゛=> バ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x8F\xE3\x82\x9A/\xE3\x83\x91/g;  # ハ+○゜=> パ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x92\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x83\x93/g;  # ヒ+○゛=> ビ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x92\xE3\x82\x9A/\xE3\x83\x94/g;  # ヒ+○゜=> ピ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x95\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x83\x96/g;  # フ+○゛=> ブ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x95\xE3\x82\x9A/\xE3\x83\x97/g;  # フ+○゜=> プ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x98\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x83\x99/g;  # ヘ+○゛=> ベ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x98\xE3\x82\x9A/\xE3\x83\x9A/g;  # ヘ+○゜=> ペ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x9B\xE3\x82\x99/\xE3\x83\x9C/g;  # ホ+○゛=> ボ
$str =~ s/\xE3\x83\x9B\xE3\x82\x9A/\xE3\x83\x9D/g;  # ホ+○゜=> ポ
```

I rewrote this for Python3:

```
def hiragana_and_katakana_normalization(file_name):
    byte_msk = file_name.encode('utf-8')
    # Hiragana
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\x8B\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\x8C')  # か+○゛=> が
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\x8D\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\x8E')  # き+○゛=> ぎ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\x8F\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\x90')  # く+○゛=> ぐ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\x91\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\x92')  # け+○゛=> げ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\x93\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\x94')  # こ+○゛=> ご
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\x95\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\x96')  # さ+○゛=> ざ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\x97\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\x98')  # し+○゛=> じ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\x99\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\x9A')  # す+○゛=> ず
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\x9B\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\x9C')  # せ+○゛=> ぜ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\x9D\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\x9E')  # そ+○゛=> ぞ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\x9F\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\xA0')  # た+○゛=> だ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xA1\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\xA2')  # ち+○゛=> ぢ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xA4\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\xA5')  # つ+○゛=> づ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xA6\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\xA7')  # て+○゛=> で
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xA8\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\xA9')  # と+○゛=> ど
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xAF\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\xB0')  # は+○゛=> ば
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xAF\xE3\x82\x9A', b'\xE3\x81\xB1')  # は+○゜=> ぱ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xB2\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\xB3')  # ひ+○゛=> び
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xB2\xE3\x82\x9A', b'\xE3\x81\xB4')  # ひ+○゜=> ぴ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xB5\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\xB6')  # ふ+○゛=> ぶ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xB5\xE3\x82\x9A', b'\xE3\x81\xB7')  # ふ+○゜=> ぷ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xB8\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\xB9')  # へ+○゛=> べ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xB8\xE3\x82\x9A', b'\xE3\x81\xBA')  # へ+○゜=> ぺ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xBB\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x81\xBC')  # ほ+○゛=> ぼ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x81\xBB\xE3\x82\x9A', b'\xE3\x81\xBD')  # ほ+○゜=> ぽ
    # Katakana
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x82\xAB\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x82\xAC')  # カ+○゛=> ガ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x82\xAD\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x82\xAE')  # キ+○゛=> ギ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x82\xAF\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x82\xB0')  # ク+○゛=> グ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x82\xB1\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x82\xB2')  # ケ+○゛=> ゲ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x82\xB3\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x82\xB4')  # コ+○゛=> ゴ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x82\xB5\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x82\xB6')  # サ+○゛=> ザ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x82\xB7\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x82\xB8')  # シ+○゛=> ジ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x82\xB9\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x82\xBA')  # ス+○゛=> ズ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x82\xBB\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x82\xBC')  # セ+○゛=> ゼ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x82\xBD\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x82\xBE')  # ソ+○゛=> ゾ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x82\xBF\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x83\x80')  # タ+○゛=> ダ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x81\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x83\x82')  # チ+○゛=> ヂ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x84\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x83\x85')  # ツ+○゛=> ヅ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x86\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x83\x87')  # テ+○゛=> デ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x88\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x83\x89')  # ト+○゛=> ド
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x8F\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x83\x90')  # ハ+○゛=> バ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x8F\xE3\x82\x9A', b'\xE3\x83\x91')  # ハ+○゜=> パ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x92\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x83\x93')  # ヒ+○゛=> ビ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x92\xE3\x82\x9A', b'\xE3\x83\x94')  # ヒ+○゜=> ピ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x95\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x83\x96')  # フ+○゛=> ブ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x95\xE3\x82\x9A', b'\xE3\x83\x97')  # フ+○゜=> プ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x98\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x83\x99')  # ヘ+○゛=> ベ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x98\xE3\x82\x9A', b'\xE3\x83\x9A')  # ヘ+○゜=> ペ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x9B\xE3\x82\x99', b'\xE3\x83\x9C')  # ホ+○゛=> ボ
    byte_msk = byte_msk.replace(b'\xE3\x83\x9B\xE3\x82\x9A', b'\xE3\x83\x9D')  # ホ+○゜=> ポ
    return byte_msk.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: For compare strings: https://igreks.jp/dev/%E6%BF%81%E7%82%B9%EF%BC%88%E3%82%9B%EF%BC%89%E3%81%A8%E5%8D%8A%E6%BF%81%E7%82%B9%EF%BC%88%E3%82%9C%EF%BC%89%E3%82%92%E5%90%AB%E3%82%80%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB/